# Disable Photoshop Elements Brush Selection with Pen and Tablet

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet, pen-tool

I have a Wacom Bamboo Tablet with pen, and every time I touch the pen down, the brush selection tool pops up instead of just drawing. I don't recall having this issue in Windows 7, but I was also using CS5 back then too.

How do I disable the brush selection tool on tap? I can't seem to find any options in PSE 11 or in the Wacom Drivers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the Bamboo preferences are set incorrectly. You first might want to update the drivers by downloading the latest version from [Wacom.com](http://www.wacom.com). Then double check the preferences to ensure you don't have the Enter or Return key set to the stylus.